# can't connect my old database to my new hostinger account

Tags: php, mysql, database, wordpress, database-connection

So, I had an old Hostinger account with all the information of my web page with some company that helped me with all of that, but we split and I created a new Hostinger account.

I tried everything to download the database I had in my old account, but nothing works, my WordPress now is disconnected, I tried to follow tutorials, uploaded my information whit FileZilla but nothing, my webpage is lost, I even uploaded mysql with php but it won't connect to the server!!

Please help!!!! What could I be doing wrong? I am so worried that I am gonna have to start over my web page, it took me a lot of time to finish it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This may be the wrong path on the server. You can try to install a clean WordPress on your site, and then transfer the whole site using this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/) or manually theme files, plugins, media using ftp manager and finally the database using this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-migrate-db/).

Comment: Herman thank you I am gonna try what you say. Do you know how I can install a clean Wordpress? I am new in this. :)

Comment: here is instruction by Hostinger https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress . of course make a copy of important files, db

Comment: How is it going?